# how to change jquery for some vertical tabs to work properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have some vertical tabs and i want to add more, but i want to add the to the right of the first vertical tabs. First ones are on the left and next to them there is the content box, well i want after this content box to be a new set of vertical tabs which will apply on the same content box. Here is an image with what i want ( i made it in photoshop ) :

[image: IMAGE is what must be here]

Here is what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/26zQS/18/
but i do not know how to change the jquery to work on both columns

### HTML

```
<div class="verticalslider" id="textExample">
    <ul class="verticalslider_tabs right">
        <li><a href="#">1-right</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2-right</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3-right</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4-right</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">5-right</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="verticalslider_tabs">
        <li><a href="#">1-left</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2-left</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3-left</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4-left</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">5-left</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="verticalslider_contents">
        <li>Nothing</li>
        <li>
                <h2>Activitate 1</h2>
ADI</li>
        <!-- elementul al doilea -->
        <li>
                <h2>Nunc Adipiscing</h2>

            <p>CUC adipiscing purus id orci rutrum placerat. Nam posuere elementum ipsum quis faucibus. Fusce fermentum turpis ac erat mollis sit amet varius mi placerat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut ante justo, varius quis dignissim nec, condimentum in dui. Nulla sed lectus eu nunc vehicula vulputate vel nec velit. Integer eu purus nunc. Donec odio augue, sagittis pellentesque adipiscing id, dignissim vel enim. Maecenas a risus est.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
                <h2>Praesent Dapibus</h2>

            <p>Praesent dapibus metus vitae velit blandit tempor. Donec dignissim tempus neque, a vestibulum massa aliquam sed. Vestibulum velit quam, facilisis vel pharetra nec, bibendum eget mauris. In vitae ligula ac justo varius ullamcorper. Nullam vitae urna eu metus pellentesque vehicula vel sit amet nibh. Cras nec velit dictum neque imperdiet congue in nec eros. Suspendisse ante felis, eleifend sed pellentesque id, sagittis ut magna. .</p>
        </li>
        <li>
                <h2>Praesent Dapibus</h2>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textExample").verticaltabs({
        speed: 500,
        slideShow: false,
        activeIndex: 0
    });
    $("#imageExample").verticaltabs({
        speed: 1000,
        slideShow: true,
        slideShowSpeed: 3000,
        activeIndex: 0,
        playPausePos: "topRight"
    });
});
```

Comment: I would propably write my own function it shouldn't be to dificult. Are You interested in function like that?

Comment: I may be a bit blind, but I can't find element with `id=imageExample`. Where is it?

Comment: @bumerang i am ok with any function as long as it works, and i will be very thankful :)

Comment: @Adi Micutzu - sorry I've been busy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my JS code, and link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uTAAU/19/
Please note, that I've change Your HTML a little

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.verticalslider_tabs li a').on('click',function(){
        var noumber = $(this).attr('id').replace('tab',''); // Here I check with element was clicked and take it noumber

        $('.verticalslider_tabs li.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab'); // I'm looking for li with class activeTab, when I get it I? remove that class
        $(this).parent().addClass('activeTab'); // Now I'm adding class activeTab to the li (parent of clickrd a element) so the border won't be displayed
        $('.verticalslider_contents li.activeContent').hide().removeClass('activeContent'); // Now I'm hidding the active tab
        $('.verticalslider_contents li[data-tab="'+noumber+'"]').fadeIn(500).addClass('activeContent'); // Here is fade in and adding activeContent class to an element
     })
});
```

Comment: wow, thanks it is what i was looking for, finally i can finish my website . Thank you ! :)

Comment: @Adi Micutzu - I'm glad I could help

Comment: actually, one more question :D , what should i change in the code so the style from css would work? (i am talking about the style that the tab has when you click it, the right/left border disappear , so you will know what tab is pressed)

Comment: Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/uTAAU/19/, I have also update code to explain what I'm doing